# Liquid div image-on-image overlay

Tags: html, css, image, scaling, fluid

I have an issue much like [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10728806/div-overlay-on-a-responsive-image), but I want to take it a step further and make my image have a height that responds fluidly to its container.

I made a thing to demonstrate [here](http://dabblet.com/gist/4158867).
What I want to do is to give the container div class "navcont" (the grey area) a fluid height. If I take out the height, I'm unable to stack similar divs in the same column, not to mention the lovely (but obligatory) overflow:hidden hiding everything.

Very appreciative of any and all help; thanks c:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do some fixes:

```
.subnav img{
    position:relative;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.navcont{
    margin: 20px;
    position:relative;
}
```